# Locus of points where difference in gravitational forces is constant

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, terminology, curves-and-surfaces

Is there a name for the curve in the plane defined by

$a/\|x - p\|^2 - b/\|x - q\|^2=\mathrm{constant}$

where $a$ and $b$ are fixed numbers and $p$ and $q$ are fixed points?  How about if I don't square the denominators?  How about if $a$ and $b$ are both $1$?

Answer (score 4):

I cannot offer names for your functions, but I was interested to see what they look like.
Here is the function with the denominators unsquared, i.e., just the distances $||p-a||$ and $||q-b||$:

        
[image: Contour Plot]

You might look at *power Voronoi diagrams*, which have a similar flavor (for multiple sites $p$, $q$).